# Can't change free trial period for in app product in Google developer console

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

We have an active in-app monthly subscription defined for our company's application. From Google developer console, I want to change the subscription's free trial period from 0 to 7 days. I enter 7 in the field, but when I click **Save** I get an error saying:

> The in-app product could not be saved. Please check the form for errors.

However, when I looked at the form, I found no errors.There's only a warning that has always been showing which says:

> Please note that you can NOT change the price and billing period for your subscription after it was activated.

But this warning has nothing to do with the free trial period. Moreover, it's clearly stated that I can update the free trial period whenever I want in this official documentation from Google under "Free Trials":

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with Google about this? I imagine they would have a support helpdesk.

Comment: Actually it worked a day later. Maybe they had a bug. Thanks anyway.

Comment: have you checked https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en